# How to pass an array properly to a threaded function with a structure

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Ive been beating my head against the wall for days about this because I cant seem to find a good solution to this issue. I need to pass two arrays into a threaded function using a structure. One array is the structure Im needing to sum and the other is where the result of that summation needs to be stored and then I need to sum them one final time in the main program to get the total value.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMBER_OF_THREADS 2


typedef struct
{
    double s[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];
    double a[];
    int tid;
} parmListType;


void *sum_arr(void *parms)
{   

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t threads[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];
    int status, i;
    double arr[1000000]={};
    double sum[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];

    printf("debug_size_arr: %ld\n",sizeof(arr)/sizeof(double));
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(arr)/sizeof(double);i++)
    {
     arr[i]=i;
    }
    parmListType *parms;

    for(i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++)
    {
        printf("debug: Main here. Creating thread %d\n", i);

        // dynamically create a structure to hold the parameter list 
        parms = (parmListType *)malloc( sizeof(parmListType));

        //printf("debug_sizeof_paramA: %ld\n",sizeof(parms->a)); 
        //parms->s[NUMBER_OF_THREADS/sizeof(double)]= *sum;
        parms->tid = i;


        status = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, sum_arr, (void *) parms);

        if(status != 0)
        {
             printf("oops. pthread_create returned error code %d\n", status);
            exit(-1);
        }
      printf("first for\n");
    }


     for(i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++)
     {
        status=pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
     }
    exit(0);
}
//// there are loads of errors in this code, I need guidance about how Im 
////supposed to set this up right.
```

Comment: "source_file.c:10:12: error: field has incomplete type 'double []'" ??? What is your plan with this member ? Sorry to say that but before trying multi threading in C, you should learn a lot more to code in C. Thread in C is not easy. Why do you need an array to store a sum aka a single value ? It would be more easy to understand if your give your  homework directly.

Comment: You can only have a flexible array member (FAM) like `double a[];` as the very last element of the structure.

Comment: You're leaking memory like fury in the first loop.  You allocate a `parmListType` and pass it to the thread, but the thread doesn't free it (or do anything else useful yet), and the main code doesn't keep track of it.

Comment: I'm familiar with loads of imperative languages, I've just never used C and I've never used threading and this is for an assignment for my operating systems course. Like I said in the comments there are a lot of little errors, I had it compiling, I broke it though just experimenting around.

Comment: So, you are learning to use a version control system, I trust?  That's how you prevent lossage from editing code that was by some definition working.

Comment: I use gitlab continous integration for my job. There is no version control for this, its just a dinky program for class to sum an array with threads, I dont want to use global space for the array, I want to allocate the array within the main function address record and pass it to each thread and have each thread work on a specific portion of it, and then each thread return its value to an array in main that will then be summed.

Comment: At the moment, it is not clear what you want to do, and your code isn't very enlightening.  Are you wanting each of your (2) worker threads to sum half the main array, and report the value back to the main thread?  Why do the worker threads need an array to report a single value?  Why don't you have a structure which contains: • pointer to data array • index to start • index to stop • sum?  The threads work on their own section of the array and report the result. You keep track of the `parmListType` pointers passed to the worker threads so you can analyze the result and free the memory.

Comment: If you lose working code, you're wasting your time and (more seriously) the time of those who would help you on SO.  Don't lose code.  Use a VCS.

Comment: That would be awesome to see an example of. Like I said Im just new to C but im not completely ignorant to the world of programming, Im senior level in undergraduate right now. Any kind of coded example showing a detailed explanation of what you just said would be amazing, and thanks again to anyone who can help.

Comment: The only thing I deleted was comments, this code is just badly written because im a noob in c and threads..

Comment: Bad exemple of bad code but that show you some logic, don't try this at home http://rextester.com/AORVQ30072, quick and dirty ! MSDOS style

Answer (score 0):

You can do st similar to the below:

```
struct ThreadArgs
{
    int type;
    //others
};

void* Thread(void* thread_args)
{
    int type;
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    type = ((struct ThreadArgs *) thread_args)->type;
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread_id;
    struct ThreadArgs* thread_args;
    thread_args = (struct ThreadArgs *) malloc(sizeof(struct ThreadArgs));
    if (thread_args == NULL)
        PanicWithError("malloc() failed");
    thread_args->type = 1;
    if (pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, Thread, (void *) thread_args) != 0)
         PanicWithError("pthread_create() failed");
    while (1)
    {}
    return 0;
}
```